# Dangling Particle Question

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-が

I encountered the following passage in a mystery manga. The detective character is explaining the evidence the "true" criminal (as opposed to the puppet killer described earlier in the book) left behind. The evidence had to do with computer data that the killer did not verify.  I've done my best to reproduce it in the layout it originally appeared in

このアンタにとって
不運な偶然としか
言えない
データ入力ミス**と**

それを
確認しなかった
アンタのイージーミス**が**

真犯人は
アンタ以外にいないという
決定証拠を

与えてしまったんだ。

Could someone please explain the function of the bold と that doesn't seem to have a いう or equivalent after it and the bold が that doesn't seem to be functioning as a subject marker or a sentence connecting particle. Part of me suspects that the が is marking the subject of 与える and I would be satisfied with that explanation. I'm very uncertain about the と though.

Comment: 「間犯人」は「真犯人」の誤字でしょうか

Comment: そうです。正しくしました。ありがとう

Answer (score 4, accepted):

が is indeed marking the subject, or rather subjects, of 与える. Everything gets a lot simpler if we string all of the text together

> このアンタにとって不運な偶然としか言えないデータ入力ミスとそれを確認しなかったアンタのイージーミスが真犯人はアンタ以外にいないという決定証拠を与えてしまったんだ。

and then parse it out like this:

> (このアンタにとって不運な偶然としか言えないデータ入力ミス)
>   **と**
>   (それを確認しなかったアンタのイージーミス)
>   **が**
>   (真犯人はアンタ以外にいないという決定証拠)
>   を与えてしまったんだ。

The subjects are our データ入力ミス and イージーミス. This looks confusing only because they both happen to have fairly substantial qualifying subordinate clauses in front of them.